# Positioning element without it being cutoff by window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following JavaScript and HTML.  The intent is to position the UL with the selected LI at the same location as the parent DIV, and it does exactly that.

Sometimes, however, the parent DIV is towards the top of the page, there are many LIs, and the selected LI is toward the bottom.  The list is positioned, however, the top of it is off the window.

How do I prevent the list from being cutoff?  Ideally, the selected element would still be positioned at the same location of the parent DIV using a scrollbar.

Thanks

```
var list=$('#myList'),
index=list.find('li.selected').index();
list.find('li.selected').removeClass('selected');
var pos=list.find('li').eq(index).addClass('selected').position();
list.css({top:  0 - pos.top, left:pos.left});

<div style="display:relative">
    <ul id="myList" style="display:absolute">
        <li>xxx</li>
        <li class="selected">xxx</li>
        <li>xxx</li>
        <li>xxx</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your divs' style says `display:relative` and `display:absolute`, while i think you mean `position:relative` and `position:absolute`.

**EDIT:**

As for your positioning, you need to manually check if the UL is to close to the top, and make sure that the top property you are setting isn't negative relative to the window. in which case you should start the top li from 0 and climb down in each iteration.

Comment: I wish to position the UL absolutely relative to the first parent which has relative position.  I think this is correct.

Comment: How would you recommend manually checking whether the UL is close to the top?

Comment: jQuery's .offset() will return the same element as position(), only relative to the document's top.

Comment: I just positioned it based on the selected LI (and forced it to be cut off), and then looked at offset(), and saw it was negative.  I can then take the negative value, and subtract it from what I was originally using to position the list.  Can this be done without actually first moving and displaying the element?